# modelManager get_by_natural key method change the USERNAME_FIELD affecting my authentication?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a custom User model that inherits from `AbstractBaseUser` which defines the username_field = email so that users will login using emails.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="Email", unique=True)
username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_site_administrator = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_developer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_project_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Last Login", auto_now=True)
create_on = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date Created", default=timezone.now)

# So that we will be working primarily with email and not username
USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username"]

objects = UserManager()
```

As the objects = UserManager() and this one contains a get_by_natural_key method as follows:

```
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        return self.get(username=username)
```

Now rather using the email to login it uses the username to login. Note that the userManager inherits from BaseUserManager like this `class UserManager(BaseUserManager):`
Can somebody explain to me what is going on here.
Is the problem coming from the inheritance or the get_by_natural_key() itself ?

Comment: You can replace that with `def get_by_natural_key(self, email): return self.get(email=email)`

Comment: Well I was using that for serializing so that it won't return the id since it is used as a foreignkey